# no matching subnet found for vpc with id vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources, terraform, subnet, vpc

I am using data resources (Terraform .12) to find the subnet_id within  the vpc and finally create ec2 instance. The VPC is getting created succesfully but I get the following error :

Error: no matching subnet found for vpc with id vpc-03a71967237294efe

However, If execute again it works.

module.my_vpc.aws_vpc.primary_vpc: Creating...

module.my_vpc.aws_vpc.primary_vpc: **Creation complete after 3s [id=vpc-03a71967237294efe]**

**Error: no matching subnet found for vpc with id vpc-03a71967237294efe**

```
Main.tf
   vpc.tf
   public_subnet.tf
   ec2.tf
```

**Here is the reproducible code:**

**Main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  profile = "work"
  shared_credentials_file=">>>>>>>>>>"
}

module "my_vpc" {
  source = "../mod/vpc"
  vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

module "pub_sub" {
  source = "../mod/pub_sub"  
  vpc_id  = "${module.my_vpc.id}"
} 

module "ec2" { 
  source = "../mod/instances"  
  vpc_id  = "${module.my_vpc.id}" 
}
```

public_subnet.tf

```
  variable "sub_cdr" {
  type="list"
  default=["10.0.0.0/28", "10.0.0.16/28"]
}
variable "azs" {
type="list"
default=["us-east-1a","us-east-1b"]
}


data "aws_availability_zones" azs {}

variable "vpc_id" { }

resource aws_subnet "public_subnet"{
count=2
vpc_id=var.vpc_id
cidr_block=var.sub_cdr[count.index]
availability_zone=data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names[count.index]
tags= {Name = "pub-sub-${count.index + 1}"} 
}

output "pub_sub_id" {
  value = aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id
}
```

ec2.tf

```
variable "vpc_id" { }

variable "instance_count" {
  default=1
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "public" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  tags = {
    Name = "*pub-sub*"
  }

}

resource "aws_security_group" "pub_sg" {
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
  name = "public-sg"
  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    to_port = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web-srvs" {
count=1
ami = "ami-035b3c7efe6d061d5"
instance_type = "t2.nano"
key_name="dell-dev"
subnet_id = element(tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.public.ids), count.index)
vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.pub_sg.id}"]
associate_public_ip_address=true
tags = { 
     CountIndex = "${var.instance_count == "0" ? "" : format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"  
   }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you attempting to retrieve a subnet that is being created later and does not exist yet?

Comment: module.pub_sub.aws_subnet.public_subnet[1]: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-0f988a979b1b3a491]
module.pub_sub.aws_subnet.public_subnet[0]: Creation complete after 1s [id=subnet-039fc6aa57e3351ea]

Error: no matching subnet found for vpc with id vpc-08ba53586e95d7260

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Subnet is getting created fine as you can see above. As mentioned earlier. However, If run terraform apply again it works !

Comment: Can you share a more fully complete [mcve]? As Matt mentioned it looks like you have a subnet resource and a data source in the same context so when Terraform runs the first time it attempts to look up a subnet and create it at the same time so the data source fails. Rerunning it would then work fine. It's possible you can ditch the data source entirely if you show the full code.

Comment: I have edited the main section and added the code to produce the error. If you run twice it works. Is it module dependency ? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can anyone take a look please. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and found that adding a depends_on clause in the aws aws_subnet_ids data component addressed it for me.

Comment: the depends_on got added in v13. I had faced this issues in v12 and module dependency was a feature request at that time. Thanks for the update.